# Why does pytz.timezone("US/Mountain").localize(datetime.datetime.now()) gives me my actual date and time and not US/Mountain's?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I want to convert a naive datetime into a non naive datetime localized in the US/Mountain. Turns out it just gives me a non naive datetime.datetime.now() with a -06:00 at the end of the datetime.

```py
naive_datetime = datetime.datetime.now() # Naive datetime

mtn_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Mountain")

naive_datetime = mtn_timezone.localize(naive_datetime)

print(naive_datetime)
```

Expected output (US/Mountain date and time):
2019-07-04 22:05:04.644687-06:00

Received output:
2019-07-05 01:05:04.644487-06:00

This received output is actually my local datetime localized in Argentina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localize` thinks the the time is correct, just missing timezone information. This is why it doesn't actually change the time.

You want `astimezone` instead, which gives the same moment in time, converted to the timezone of choice:

```
mtn_datetime = naive_datetime.astimezone(mtn_timezone)
```

Comment: ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime

Comment: That's weird. It works on my Python 3.6.5. Are you possibly using Python2? If so, [why](https://pythonclock.org)? :P (You can localize to Argentina, then convert to Mountain)